# how do i configure applicationcontext.xml in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, struts2

when i put struts.xml in web-inf it is showing error......when i put in src folder it is working fine.(being applicationcontext.xml in web-inf)

(being struts.xml in (src folder or src/resources)) when i put applicationcontext.xml in src folder.........it is saying that unable to find  applicationcontext.xml  in web-inf folder...........it is not able to execute.

how do i configure so that eclipse can find the path of struts.xml or applicationcontext.xml so that wherever i put it should detect it.

the code in web.xml is as follows.

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Thank you all.

Comment: I dont think you can configure eclipse so that wherever you keep struts.xml or applicationcontext.xml it will be accepted. It is better to keep struts.xml in src folder and applicationcontext.xml in web-inf. answer given by kandarp will be helpfull in specifying path of applicationcontext.xml for spring. I dont think something like this is available for struts2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure context-param in web.xml like below:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value> /WEB-INF/application-context.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

And put your application-context.xml in WEB-INF folder.

Comment: do you have below entries in we.xml?
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>xyz</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>xyz</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>


NOTE: in place of xyz, please specify your own servlet mapping name

Comment: Please go thorugh below link. They clearly defined how we can configure struts and spring in our application.


http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/web-integration.html

Answer (score 2):

if you are putting in web-inf folder

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

if you are putting in src/resource folder

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

one more thing if you get the error like the below link after doing modification.

http://www.bpjava.net/Struts2_Configuration_Plugin/config-browser/showBeans.action

the solution is given at end.

or you can do the following.

in struts.xml `<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />`